# How do I disable 1 of the 2 input devices that share a key in Generic.kl?

Tags: game-controllers

As the title says really, my Gamepad button A and Fingerprint scanner share a key in the generic keylayout file. I'm running Resurrection Remix ROM on a Xiaomi Mi Max, if that's any use.

I'd like to stop the fingerprint scanner acting as a button but keep my gamepad button usable. Is this possible? I'm presuming it may have to be done a deeper level than the keylout file itself.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the resolution in the end. I had to replace the system library files (in "system/lib/hw/" and "system/lib64/hw/") for the Fingerprint Scanner to a version that they didn't trigger a key in generic.kl.